# first is not a function

Tags: jquery

I am a noob in Jquery and I am playing around with the different selectors and functions right now. I am trying to do this

```
$('li').first();
```

on firefox console and I got

```
TypeError: $("li").first is not a function
```

when

```
$('li')
```

returns

```
Object { length=8, 0=li, 1=li, more...}
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Absolutely no idea! Which version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: what version of JQuery are you using?

Comment: and in what context are you using `$('li').first()`? Are you assigning it to a variable? It may not like just being on one line of code like that.

Comment: the one that jquery in action 2 uses. Which I believe is 1.2.1

Comment: Does jQuery("li").first() work?

Comment: @ElRonnoco Doesn't like being on one line like that?!

Comment: @Dave: He means "not assigned to anything", which is silly.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You said in a comment that you're using jQuery 1.2.1, which is ancient ([over four years old](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery#Release_history)).

The [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/first/) states quite clearly that `.first()` was added in jQuery 1.4.

Answer (score 1):

Two possibilities I see:

Firstly, you're using JQuery 1.3. The `first()` function was added in v1.4 (see http://api.jquery.com/first/). If this is the case, you need to upgrade immediately. The current version is 1.6, so you're well behind the curve, and there will be a lot of functionality that won't work in older versions.

The other possibility is that you're also including another library as well as JQuery that also defines the `$()` function (eg Mootools or Prototype). It's generally not a good idea to do this, but if you are including more than one library and you can't avoid it, you will need to run JQuery in compatibility mode, and reference it with the `JQuery()` function name instead of `$()`.

Answer (score 1):

Old jQuery (<1.4, >=1.1.2) can use `.eq(0)` for `.first()`

Like first(), it returns a jQuery object.

`jQuery('*').find('a').eq(0)`

Why bother? Wordpress 2.8 uses jQuery 1.3.2, and if you are supposed to code for that, you may need it.